# Should I say "Your order is now complete" or "Your order is now completed"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

When a user finishes an order on my website, what's the correct way?

> - Your order is now **complete**.
> - Your order is now **completed**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I prefer "Your order is complete"; the "now" doesn't add anything.  The second sentence uses a present-tense verb with a past-tense adjective.

Comment: past-tense adjective?? you mean verb...

Comment: Let's settle for [past participle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Past_participle#English).

Comment: "past-tense adjective??"  I don't think so; "completed" modifies the noun "order".

Comment: I would argue that the 'now' in 'now complete' adds information that it was until just recently not complete.

Comment: "past-tense adjective" - no such thing

Answer (score 9):

*Completed* in the phrase *is completed* is used as an adjective, in the same way of *warmed* in *one is warmed by a stove for visitors*.

Searching for *is completed* and *is complete* in the *Corpus of Contemporary American*, I get the following data (the chart reports the frequency per million of those phrases).

[image: "is complete" vs. "is completed"]

Looking for *is now completed*, and *is now complete*, I get the following data:

[image]

To make a comparison, this is the data I get when searching for *was completed*, and *was complete*:

[image]

Looking at these charts, I can say that:

- The phrases *is now completed* and *is now complete* are less common than the equivalent phrases without *now*.
- The "rule" "use *complete* with *is*, use *completed* with *was*" seems to not be generally applicable. In academic and spoken context, both *is completed* and *is complete* have the same frequency; in magazine context, that is not true, and *is complete*, *was completed* are used more times than *is completed* and *was complete*.

Comment: If you are wondering why all in a sudden you see two mouse cursors, that is because one cursor is in the screenshots I took. It wanted to appear, and I thought it could have been fine as ruler.

Comment: You're insane...

Comment: This is wrong. "warmed" as "one is warmed by a stove for visitors" is a verb not an adjective. Same with "completed"

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence is absolutely right. It is the Passive Voice. In the first sentence it is the Active Voice. I think it's correct, too. But I like the other version more..

> The finished product will be ready and available after two weeks have passed. It will be completed in two weeks. The finished product will be ready and available after two weeks have passed.

OR

> The product will be worked on during a period of two weeks, making it finished, ready, and available at the end of the two-week period.

In the first case, you are allowing for the possibility that work on the product may not start until 10, 11, maybe 12 days after you utter the statement.

In the second case, you may be saying the same thing as in the first case, OR, you may be saying that work on the product will be carried on during the entire two-week period.

Comment: Sentence #2 is not passive voice. It is *completed* as an adjective.  This is clear because it is supposed to be a discrete event that just happened.  The phrase "is completed" as a passive would express a habitual action, e.g. "is completed once per day".  If you wanted to use the passive to express the situation described in the question, you would use "has been completed".  Therefore, in order to convey the proper meaning, "is completed" here is used with the stative verb *is* plus the adjective *completed*.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: I had been wondering why “Your order is completed” is grammatical.  Thanks!