# Complete or Completed

Tags: american-english

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I say “Your order is now complete” or “Your order is now completed”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4361/should-i-say-your-order-is-now-complete-or-your-order-is-now-completed)

**What is better, "complete" or "completed"?**

I want to know which sounds the most encouraging. Which of these two promotes more of an elation or satisfaction of accomplishment.

Personally I'm leaning towards "completed" as the "d" suffix bring a more substantial and abrupt ending, which to me more clearly signifies the significance of the accomplished item.

Comment: I saw that, but do not feel it applies as this is more of an abstracted discussion untethered to usage.

Comment: Can we have a look at the use case in question?

Comment: Think "to-do list," but there really is no use-case

Comment: I'm confused: if there is no use case, then what is the question referring to when it says "In this use-case"?

Comment: To reply to this question, I would say exactly what I have already said in reply to [another question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4361/should-i-say-your-order-is-now-complete-or-your-order-is-now-completed/11892#11892).

Comment: Am I missing the example 'use-case'?  What is the proposed sentence where 'complete' or 'completed' will be used?

Comment: *Edited question*

Comment: This is marked as duplicate, but the answers here provide a better explanation.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

*Complete*, unlike *completed*, implies something whole or full.
*Completed* means *finished, accomplished, or done.*

A lot of the meaning overlaps, but I think *completed* gives a better sense of accomplishment, though it really depends on how you're using it.

Comment: +1 Some examples, using 'complete' and 'completed' as adjectives:  A *complete* book is one that is not missing any pages.  A *completed* book is one that an author has finished writing.  A *complete* job assignment includes a full set of instructions and a due date.  A *completed* job assignment results in payment for services rendered.

Answer (score 3):

"Complete" indicates a thing that has been finished. "Completed" is a past-tense verb form, and while by itself means much the same thing as "complete", it has the additional implication of something that *has been finished*, and as a consequence, the word has additional implications of the process that completed the thing. I would go with "completed".

Comment: My understanding is "complete" is similar to "perfect", so it should go with some things like books, persons, and machines,... It usually stands before the noun.
"completed" is for the finished process, so it should go with some things like voyages, and steps in the process... It usually stands after the "to be" to say some things were finished.